# ¿Como restar datos de una misma columna en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

Buen día.

Tengo una tabla **Table** donde tengo 2 columnas:

- **Unidad**(Donde se encuentran los numeros seriales de las piezas producidas)
- **Fecha** (Columna donde se almacena la hora en la que la pieza fue producida).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero Realizar un query el cual me muestre la diferencia de segundos que existe entre cada pieza.

Hice un query que practicamente lo que hace es tomar la columna **Fecha** y la manda a otra temporal llamada **#Temporal** y le asigna un **ID**.

Despues, usando como base esta tabla **#Temporal**, selecciono los **ID** Impares (1,3, 5 y 7 etc) y los Pares (2,4,6,8) los cuales los guarda en dos tablas temporales: **#Par** e **#Impar** respectivmente.

Para despues con un `Left Join` acomodar en una sola tabla las dos tablas en 2 columnas **Par** e **Impar** y por ultimo yo solo saco la diferencia mediante un `Datediff(seconds, Par, Impar)`.

Les adjunto el query:

```
DECLARE @Day DATE = '2023-03-24' --GETDATE()  SELECT @Day
DECLARE @Date Date = CONVERT(DATE,@Day)
DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(30) = DATEPART(yy,@Day)
DECLARE @Date1 NVARCHAR(40) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Date,21)

DECLARE @StartDateTime DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME,@Date)
SET @StartDateTime = DATEADD(HOUR,7,@StartDateTime)

DECLARE @EndDateTime  DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME,@Date)
SET @EndDateTime = DATEADD(HOUR,12,DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,@StartDateTime))


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

SELECT MachineCode as Code, Count(ActualNo) as Cuenta into #Decission FROM [Table] WHERE 
DBW_DateTime BETWEEN '''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@StartDateTime,21)+''' AND 
'''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@EndDateTime,21)+''' 
AND PLCNo= 1 GROUP BY MachineCode ORDER BY MachineCode ASC

DECLARE @MC INT = (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM #Decission WHERE Cuenta = (SELECT MAX(Cuenta) FROM #Decission))

CREATE TABLE #Temporal
(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Fecha Time)

INSERT INTO #Temporal (Fecha)
SELECT TOP(10) DBW_DateTime FROM [Table] WHERE DBW_DateTime 
BETWEEN  '''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@StartDateTime,21) +'''  AND '''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@EndDateTime,21) +'''  and PLCNo = 1 AND MachineCode = @MC ORDER BY DBW_DateTime ASC



CREATE TABLE #Impar
(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Fecha Time)

INSERT INTO #Impar(Fecha)
SELECT Fecha FROM #Temporal WHERE (ID % 2) <> 0

CREATE TABLE #Par
(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Fecha2 Time)

INSERT INTO #Par(Fecha2)
SELECT Fecha FROM #Temporal WHERE (ID % 2) = 0


SELECT Fecha, Fecha2
into #Final FROM #Impar
LEFT JOIN #Par
ON #Impar.ID = #Par.ID



SELECT Fecha, Fecha2, DATEDIFF(second, Fecha, Fecha2)/60.00 as Segundos into #Dif FROM #Final

SELECT Fecha, Fecha2 ,Segundos FROM #Dif    



DROP TABLE #Temporal
DROP TABLE #Decission
DROP TABLE #Par
DROP TABLE #Impar
DROP TABLE #Final
DROP TABLE #Dif

'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Dándome esto como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por un momento pense que funcionó, pero me di cuenta que estoy omitiendo una resta.

Esto lo noté al comprobar mi Query en excel, por ejemplo: en teoría hago la resta en la fila 1 donde resto la columna 2 (Fecha2) menos la 1 (Fecha). Hasta aquíi todo bien, pero despues necesito restar la unidad de la siguiente fila, que sería la celda 1 de la fila 2 menos la celda 2 de la fila 1 para tambien sacar la diferencia de esas unidades. Como conclusion mi query esta mal porque omite una celda.

Lo que me gustaría obtener seria un resultado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es aquí donde solicito su apoyo para corregir este fallo y que todas las celdas de esa columna se puedan restar sin hacer omisión de alguna.

Se que probablemente mi query y mi lógica puedan ser mas sencillas, y que inclusive con una sola sentencia se pueda hacer esto, solo que sigo aprendiendo y es lo que se me ocurrió.

Cualquier apoyo se los agradecería. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya recibiste una buena respuesta, pero tu código tiene problemas serios. Estás escribiendo código dinámico cuando no es necesario y estás concatenando valores en vez de parametrizar la consulta. Este hábito puede abrir las puertas a problemas de seguridad por inyección de SQL.

Comment: Hola! si me imagine que tengo muchos errores y areas de oportunidad para mejorar, sigo aprendiendo. Tomare muy en cuenta tus comentarios para evitar malas practicas, muchas gracias por tu apoyo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `LEAD()` para obtener el valor de la siguiente fila y/o pasarlo como tercer parámetro en la función `DATEDIFF()`.

Teniendo estos datos de entrada:

```
CREATE TABLE datos
(unidad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, fecha TIME NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO datos VALUES 
('Q325834', '07:09:45'), 
('Q325835', '07:10:47'), 
('Q325836', '07:11:31'), 
('Q325837', '07:12:19'), 
('Q325838', '07:13:06'), 
('Q325839', '07:13:46'), 
('Q325840', '07:14:58')
```

El query quedaría así:

```
SELECT 
    unidad,
    fecha,
    LEAD(fecha,1) OVER (
        ORDER BY unidad
    ) siguiente_hora,
    DATEDIFF(ss, fecha, (LEAD(fecha,1) OVER (ORDER BY unidad))) diferencia_en_segundos
FROM 
    datos;
```

Y la salida sería esta:

| unidad | fecha | siguiente_hora | diferencia_en_segundos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q325834 | 07:09:45.0000000 | 07:10:47.0000000 | 62 |
| Q325835 | 07:10:47.0000000 | 07:11:31.0000000 | 44 |
| Q325836 | 07:11:31.0000000 | 07:12:19.0000000 | 48 |
| Q325837 | 07:12:19.0000000 | 07:13:06.0000000 | 47 |
| Q325838 | 07:13:06.0000000 | 07:13:46.0000000 | 40 |
| Q325839 | 07:13:46.0000000 | 07:14:58.0000000 | 72 |
| Q325840 | 07:14:58.0000000 | (null) | (null) |

**Una breve explicación:**

- A la función `LEAD(returnValue, offset)`, se le envían los parámetros **fecha** y la cantidad de filas que queremos obtener a partir de la fila actual, para este caso, **1**.
- Para tus datos, no se requiere la cláusula `PARTITION BY` sino que basta con `ORDER BY`.
- El resultado se le pasa como tercer parámetro a la función `DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, enddate)`.
- La última fila no tiene datos para comparar y por eso retorna *null*.
- Puedes omitir la tercera columna **siguiente_hora**, solo la usé con fines ilustrativos.

Si te quedan dudas, deja un comentario.

Comment: Sería más apropiado usar la función LAG() puesto que quiere comparar con la fila anterior.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya probe el codigo y todo parece funcionar excelente, te agradezco mucho tu apoyo, sabia que habia una maner mucho mas sencilla, tendre que seguir documentandome, una vez mas gracias!